# How does recursion work in a divide and conquer maxima set algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

Here is a pseudo code algorithm from an algorithm textbook by Goodrich for finding the dominating 2D points in a set of points, known as finding maxima sets:

```
Algorithm MaximaSet(S):

Input: A set,S,of n points in the plane

Output: The set, M, of maxima points in S 

if n ≤ 1

then return S  

Let p be the median point in S, by lexicographic (x,y)-coordinates 

Let L be the set of points lexicographically less than p in S 

Let G be the set of points lexicographically greater than or equal to p in S 

 M1 ←MaximaSet(L) 
 M2 ←MaximaSet(G) 

 Let q be the lexicographically smallest point in M2 

  for each point, r, in M1 do 

              if x(r) ≤ x(q) and y(r) ≤ y(q) 

              then Remove r from M1 

 return M1 ∪ M2
```

My question is in the two recursive calls at line 10,11. My understanding is that the first calls for M1 at line 10 will break the L side into another L and G set, and then the next L into another L and G set, until one set remains, the the next line will run and do the same thing to the G side for M2, but now how does it do the comparisons with q? Can someone help me trace the conquer part of this algorithm?

Given

(1,4) (2,6), ( 3,1) (4,5) (5,7) (6,9) (7,2), (8,6) (9,3)

I know the maxima set is (6,9) (8,6) (9,3) but I am stuck on how exactly that came to light using THIS algorithm. I solved it via brute force.  This started as a HW question, and I technically can move on because I did find the answer, but I really need to get an understanding of this and I've tried 2 textbooks and google but I think I need a person this time. Thank you in advance and since this is my first time on stack please don't hesitate to (kindly, please) give me any corrections to how I asked my question or presented my p-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the conquer part is that, you have to assumed the returned set `M1` & `M2` fulfilled this condition:

> Any pair of points in the same set can be co-existing

That is, any pair of the points in the set must fulfilled `x1 < x2 && y1 > y2`

And after you merge `M1` and `M2`, you should return a set fulfilling this condition too, and at last the set we obtain is the answer.

One point to note that is, I think when merging, `x` is actually not needed to be compared, as all points in `M1` should have `x` <= than those in `M2`

---

We use `q`, the first point in `M2` to compared with all points in `M1`, because

1. As mentioned, `q` does not need to compared with other elements in `M2`
2. Visually, `q` is the point with smallest `x` and largest `y` in `M2`, as mentioned, all `M1`'s `x` should be smaller than all points in `M2`, so the main point here is `q` has largest `y` in `M2`, thus the largest "potential" to cover (elminitate) points in `M1`

Combined 1 & 2, the algorithm uses `q` to compare all points in `M1` to try to eliminate hopeless candidates, and union those left with `M2` to form a new set which fulfilled mentioned condition.

---

Let's do a demo using your example:

Divide:
(1,4) (2,6) (3,1) (4,5) (5,7) (6,9) (7,2) (8,6) (9,3); **L** = (1,4) (2,6), ( 3,1) (4,5) (5,7); **R** =  (6,9) (7,2), (8,6) (9,3)

Divide:
(1,4) (2,6) (3,1) (4,5) (5,7); **L** = (1,4) (2,6), (3,1); **R** =  (4,5) (5,7)

Divide: 
(1,4) (2,6) (3,1);  **L** = (1,4) (2,6);  **R** = (3,1), **Return {(3,1})**

Divide:
(1,4) (2,6); **L** = (1,4); **Return {(1,4)}**; **R** = (2,6); **Return {(2,6)}**

Divide:
(4,5) (5,7); **L** = (4,5); **Return {(4,5)}**; **R** = (5,7); **Return {(5,7)}**

Conquer:
(1,4) (2,6); **M1** = {(1,4)}; **M2** = {(2,6)}  **q** = (2,6); **return merged set** = {(2,6)}

Conquer:
(1,4) (2,6) (3,1); **M1** = {(2,6)}; **M2** = {(3,1)}; **q** = (3,1); **return merged set** = {(2,6), (3,1)}

Conquer:
(4,5) (5,7); **M1** = {(4,5)}; **M2** = {(5,7)}; **q** = (5,7); **return merged set** = {(5,7)}

Conquer:
(1,4) (2,6) (3,1) (4,5) (5,7); **M1** = {(2,6), (3,1)}; **M2** = {(5,7)}; **q** = (5,7); **return merged set** = {(5,7)}

Divide:
(6,9) (7,2) (8,6) (9,3); **L** = (6,9) (7,2); **R** =  (8,6) (9,3)

Divide:
(6,9) (7,2); **L** = (6,9); **Return {(6,9})**; **R** = (7,2); **Return {(7,2)}**

Divide:
(8,6) (9,3); **L** = (8,6); **Return {(8,6)}**; **R** = (9,3), **Return {(9,3)}**

Conquer:
(6,9) (7,2); **M1** = {(6,9)}; **M2** = {(7,2)}; **q** = (7,2); **return merged set** = {(6,9), (7,2)}

Conquer:
(8,6) (9,3); **M1** = {(8,6)}; **M2** = {(9,3)}; **q** = (9,3); **return merged set** = {(8,6), (9,3)}

Conquer:
(6,9) (7,2) (8,6) (9,3); **M1** = {(6,9), (7,2)}; **M2** = {(8,6), (9,3)}; **q** = (8,6); **return merged set** = {(6,9), (8,6), (9,3)}

Conquer:
(1,4) (2,6) (3,1) (4,5) (5,7) (6,9) (7,2) (8,6) (9,3); **L** = (1,4) (2,6) (3,1) (4,5) (5,7); **M1** = {(5,7)}, **M2** = {(6,9), (8,6), (9,3)}; **q** = (6,9); **return merged set** = {(6,9), (8,6), (9,3)}

==> **Return** {(6,9), (8,6), (9,3)}

Comment: This is an amazing answer, shole, and I am very grateful to you for taking the time to do this! I understand it now. Thank you so much, and I have accepted your answer.